# HTML/CSS Whitespace under footer

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm having a problem with a white space underneath the footer. I've searched on Stack Overflow and can't seem to find an answer that works for me, so hopefully somebody can help me with my specific issue.

Things that I've noticed:

1. I can't inspect this whitespace at all. I've tried inspecting everything with the dev tools, but it looks to be outside of HTML.
2. This is a Rails project. I removed the `<%= yield %>` tag to see if it's a space coming from another page/partial, but the space still remains after removing that `<%= yield %>` tag.
3. I am not using any Javascript files

`application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DoINeedAJacket</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <%= yield %>
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <ul>
      <%= link_to image_tag('facebook-1.png', size: '32x32'), '####' %>
      <%= link_to image_tag('twitter-1.png', size: '32x32'), '####' %>
      <%= link_to image_tag('linkedin-1.png', size: '32x32'), '####' %>
      <%= link_to image_tag('github-1.png', size: '32x32'), '####' %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`application.css.scss`

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 97%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -3em;
}

.footer, .push {
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    img {
      margin: 0.5rem;
    }
  }
}
```

The reason I have height set to 97% is because there's some scroll space that I needed to get rid of. If there's a better way to do that, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative;` to `.wrapper`

And `position:absolute;
     bottom:0;`
to your `footer`

Comment: while this does force the elements to be on the bottom of the page, it doesn't explain what that white space is at the bottom. or at least the white space is still showing at the bottom

Comment: I presume the whitespace is the html{ height:97%; }. A live link would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That is the CSS for no margin in footer (no SCSS, only CSS):

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    html {
      height: 97%;
    }
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
      min-height: 100%;
      height: auto !important;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto -3em;
    }

    .footer, .push {
      height: 3em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: .5rem;
    }
    .footer  ul, .push  ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }

    .footer  ul img, .push  ul img {
      margin: 0.5rem;
    }
```